# Vertically align first table row with text with booktabs' toprule

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, booktabs

A top-aligned `tabular` aligns the baseline of its first row with the base line of the surrounding text. However, when using `booktabs`' `\toprule`, the rule is considered the first row and thus aligned with this baseline.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

this is some text
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
  o & p \\
  q & r \\
\end{tabular}
this is some text

this is some text
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l}\toprule
  o & p \\
  q & r \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
this is some text

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

How can I align the first "real" row of the `tabular` with a `\toprule` with the surrounding line?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

this is some text
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
  o & p \\
  q & r \\
\end{tabular}
this is some text

this is some text
\begin{NiceTabular}[t]{l l}\toprule
  o & p \\
  q & r \\\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
this is some text

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

One option is to fake the `booktabs` rules using `tcolorbox`. The resulting syntax is not as nice as using `nicematrix`, as suggested in [F. Pantigny's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621341/48973), but it works after compiling just once. (One could of course write a wrapper environment.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{fakebooktabsrules}{
  hbox,
  nobeforeafter,
  tcbox raise base,
  arc=0pt,
  boxrule=\heavyrulewidth,
  leftrule=0pt,
  rightrule=0pt,
  boxsep=0pt,
  top=\belowrulesep,
  bottom=\aboverulesep,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  colback=white,
  colframe=.,
}

\begin{document}

this is some text
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
  o & p \\
  q & r \\
\end{tabular}
this is some text

this is some text
\begin{tabular}[t]{l l}\toprule
  o & p \\
  q & r \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
this is some text

this is some text
\begin{fakebooktabsrules}
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l l}
    o & p \\
    q & r \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{fakebooktabsrules}
this is some text

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]